# Is it allowed to exit the runway by opposites High Speed Taxiway?

Tags: faa-regulations, airport, taxiways

Is it allowed to exit the runway on a High Speed Taxiway to the opposite side? (see red line in image below). Assume the situation allows it, like airplane limits, airport congestion, weather, etc.

[image]

Comment: Yes.  One of the airlines I flew for prohibited the use of high speeds.  We had to slow on the runway and exit at a standard or reverse unless they were unavailable.  It was part of the opspecs, not just an informal rule.

Answer (score 5):

It's not really a regulation question, at least not in the way you think. There's 2 possibilities:

1. A controlled airfield: in an airfield which has air traffic control all movements require a clearance, if the tower clears an airplane to use a taxiway then that is all that airplane is allowed to do unless there's an emergency of some kind. It would be unusual for ATC to direct an airplane to use a taxiway which has such a tight turn, but there's no reason they wouldn't if it the situation called for it
2. An uncontrolled airfield: in this situation there's nobody in a tower telling pilots what to do, all movements are at pilots' discretion. Pilots can use any taxiway in any way they please as long as it doesn't put them in potential conflict with another airplane

Answer (score 1):

yes this is allowed, and common at certain airports

If you land in such a manner to come to a reasonable taxi/turn speed where the closest available exit taxiway is a "opposite high speed" taxiway, At this point you can either taxi forward to the next available 90 or high speed, -OR- use the closest "opposite high speed"

Tower and other landing traffic will usually perfer that you exit via the nearest taxiway